# How to make audio driver for MS-DOS?

Tags: assembly, audio, driver, dos, x86-16

I want to make audio driver for MS-DOS in assembly 8086 that will send the Tandy sound from games and other software to the PC speaker on non-Tandy 1000 computers (Computers that don't have the Tandy 1000 sound chip).

Comment: for dos you write the driver thats kinda the deal there.  you need to know if the machine has sound support at all then emulate it.

Comment: Check out [this project](http://www.oldskool.org/pc/tand-em) which basically does the same thing you want to do.

Comment: @old_timer “just do it” is not a good answer to “how do I” questions.

Comment: too broad.  How do I make a car from scratch please write that down in a paragraph to cover all possibilities, use cases, configurations.

Comment: how do I questions are not stackoverflow questions. please edit this to make it a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit difficult to achieve.  The Tandy sound card works by writing data to port `0xc0`.  In order to emulate the sound card, you need to intercept writes to that port and handle them with your software.  This is impossible on the 8086 and not possible in a sensible manner for real mode software on the 80286, so you need at least an 80386 for this to work.

The key idea is to kick your CPU into Virtual 8086 mode and then provide it with an IO permission mask that is 0 everywhere except for ports 0xc0–0xc7.  This causes all hardware accesses to work except when you try to access the Tandy sound card.  In this case, you get a VM exit which you can use to emulate the hardware.

A similar thing has been done for LPT port adlib cards in [this project](https://github.com/pdewacht/adlipt/tree/master/adlipt).  You should be able to adapt the code for your purpose.

Note that this leaves the question on how to actually emulate the sound card's sound entirely open.  I can't help you with that.  The Tandy used an SN76489 chip to generate its sound, so check out if other people have tried to emulate it before, I guess.

Comment: No problem, I had already upvoted despite that.